# CSS Styles not reflecting in IE10

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer-10

Trying to apply styles for a `td` inside `table` using the following below code.

I am using a jQuery method for which I am passing the parameters from the server side using

> [AjaxPro.AjaxMethod(AjaxPro.HttpSessionStateRequirement.Read)]

The params are getting passed but `padding` is not applying, Height and width are displaying currently though.

```
$("#tdTest").css({
    height: height + "px",
    width: width + "px",
    paddingLeft: paddingFrontLeft + "px",
    paddingRight: paddingFrontRight + "px",
    paddingTop: paddingFrontTop + "px",
    paddingBottom: paddingFrontBottom + "px"
}
```

Please suggest me any ways to rectify this.
The styles are getting applied in IE8 though, but no changes in style in IE9,IE10 and chrome.

Comment: PADDING: `Applies to all elements except table-row-group, table-header-group, table-footer-group, table-row, table-column-group and table-column`  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS%2Fpadding

Comment: Also, IE9 and 10 have some known issues with padding, especially on inputs and something to do with box-sizing if I remember correctly ?

Comment: This is the table am using

Comment: <div style="overflow-x: auto; overflow-y:hidden; width:814px;">                             
<table id="tblMain" style="min-width:100px; width:auto;" cellpadding="0">
<tr><td id="tdDroppable" class="tdSelect" style="background-color: Gray;height:100px;width:80px;padding:20px;">
<div id="droppable" runat="server" class="ui-widget-content" style="background-color: white;">
</div></td><td id="tdPartition" style="display:none;padding:0px;"></td>
<td id="tdDroppable1" class="tdSelect" style="background-color: Gray;height:100px;width:80px;padding:20px;">

Comment: <div id="divBack" runat="server" class="ui-widget-content" style="background-color: white;">
</div></td></tr></table></div>

Comment: Please let me know if there is any mistake on the table layout part. tdTest in my Post is same as tdDroppable in my table layout